# PHP: насколько эффективна защита "defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.')"?

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть ли смысл использовать защиту вида:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');
```

У меня вызывает сомнение необходимость её применения для файлов классов, т.е.:

```
<?php class Foo { /* code */ }
```

Нужна ли она для файлов вида:

```
<?php return array('param' => 'val', 'param2' => 'val2');
```

Comment: А вообще зачем она тебе?

Answer (score 1):

[@Антон Шаманов](/users/13838/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), если делать все по PSR (файлы либо совершают действия, либо содержат объявления), то ее необходимость просто отпадает. Прямой вызов объявит класс и завершит скрипт, вернув статус 200 и пустое тело ответа (или 500).

Однако хорошим тоном будет вообще вукинуть весь код из доступной зоны, сделав `DOCUMENT_ROOT` какую-нибудь подпапку типа `public` и оставив в ней только `index.php`, который будет вызывать код из вышележащих папок.

Comment: @Fike я пишу с учетом того, что '.htaccess' может отсутствовать.